# How to change position in MPAndroidChart PieChart color indicator

Tags: pie-chart, mpandroidchart, indicator

I am working on MPAndroidChart and I want to change position of PieChart color indicator.

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

When i set `android:layout_width="200dp"` and `android:layout_height="200dp"` It apply height and width whole view.

I want to only make distance between `PieChart` and its color indicator.
Don't want to overlap indicator on `PieChart` View

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/chart1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
        l.setPosition(LegendPosition.LEFT_OF_CHART);
        l.setXEntrySpace(7f);
        l.setYEntrySpace(5f);
        l.setYOffset(0f);
```

OR

```
Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
        l.setPosition(LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART_CENTER);
        l.setXEntrySpace(7f);
        l.setYEntrySpace(5f);
        l.setYOffset(0f);
```

Comment: @ShaiIesh : I need output as expected result

Comment: setPosition() is deprecated now.

Comment: @Palak did you got the output?

Comment: @Wini: Yes, Did you tried with this solution?

Comment: @Palak yes...but this solution is not working as setposition is showing error....can you please up your solution below

Answer (score 1):

You can set position of color indicators like LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART,LegendPosition.BELOW_CHART_LEFT etc.

```
Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
        l.setPosition(LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART);
        l.setXEntrySpace(7f);
        l.setYEntrySpace(5f);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Legend l = mChart.getLegend();

l.setPosition(LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART;
l.setXEntrySpace(7f);
l.setYEntrySpace(5f);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: You somehow managed to add what seems to be a syntax error while copying from the eixisting answer(s). If you cannot contribute any additional insight I recommend to delete this post, rather than fixing the error.